# Use AspectJ in an android library project

Tags: android, aspectj

I want to try and use AspectJ as part of an android library project. I tried creating an android library project and used annotation based style to create pointcuts.

The problem is that the aspects of the library project does not get weaved into the android application which has added my library project.

My Android library project has few aspects defined in it. Something like

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* *.*(..)) && !this(com.xyz.aspects.xyz)")
public void abc(JoinPoint jp) 
{ 
    dosomething;
}
```

I've added this library project to my android application. However the 'dosomething' is not executed. Any advices?

Comment: My advice is: Show us some code and configuration details. Otherwise it is like asking: "I want to cook a meal. Any advice?"

Comment: @kriegaex have added some code. see now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
execution(* *(..)) && !within(com.xyz.aspects.xyz..*)
```

I have not tested it, just quickly written it with my iPad, but maybe it helps. Keep me updated if it does not.

Comment: Yes, it will - unless you have a problem in your Spring or AspectJ configuration, which still you have not posted. Does aspect weaving work with ANY kind of pointcut/advice? The pointcut code you posted is definitely wrong!

Comment: Why wouldnt that work?. Its perfectly working on my android project. I can see that its getting woven. But anyways, the question is how do I use annotation based aspects to be woven into an android project by using normal java compiler

Comment: Because your `this` pointcut seems to be a package name. It should be (or match) a class name.

Comment: com.xyz.aspects.xyz was intended to be a class name placeholder. Any idea how to compile annotation based aspects via normal java compiler. Can you give me a sample code ?

Comment: Because your class name started with a lower-case letter, I thought that by convention you meant a package. As for the other question: Yes, I can, when I am back home in a few days.

Comment: Will be looking forward to that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Finally fixed this. I added the library project to my aspect path and things started to work.

Comment: Can you tell me how thats done ? having the same issue right now

Comment: I had added the aspectj plugin for eclipse to weave in the code. Right now there are much better ways to do it. Checkout : https://github.com/uPhyca/gradle-android-aspectj-plugin

Comment: I figured it out . That's my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142125/aspectj-with-android-library/31225630#31225630